# A restriction on defining set in subset axiom

Tags: set-theory, axioms

**Subset axioms**$\;\;\;$ For each formula $\varphi$ not containing $B$, the following is an axiom:
$$\forall t_{1}\cdots\forall t_{k}\,\forall c\,\exists B\,\forall x(x\in B \iff x\in c \;\&\; \varphi)$$

**Choice axiom**$\;\;\;\;\;(\forall\; \text{relation}\;R)(\exists\; \text{function} \;F)(F \subseteq R \;\&\; \text{dom}\; F = \text{dom}\; R)$

If $\varphi$ can contain $B$, axiom of choice could be derived from subset axiom. But why can't $\varphi$ contain $B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, because the point of the axiom is to define the set $B = \{x \in c \mid \varphi\}$. So we can't use $B$ in the definition of $B$.

Looking directly at the axiom, one thing that could go wrong if we allowed $\varphi$ to contain $B$ is the special case
$$
    \forall t_{1}\cdots\forall t_{k}\,\forall c\,\exists B\,\forall x(x\in B \iff x\in c \land x\notin B)
$$
This can't possibly be the case for any $c \ne \varnothing$, because for every element of $c$, it says that $x \in B \iff x \notin B$.